# Implement Photo gallery in static Table View Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, photo-gallery

I have a table view presenting information about specific objects and I want the very first static cell to contain a photo gallery with a variable number of pictures.

Is it possible to just make a collectionview the subview of the static table view cell and implement all the collectionview methods or is there a better way to achieve this.

I did a research, but couldn't find any usable demonstrations..

PS: I do everything programmatically, without the use of storyboards or xibs and I am fairly beginner in programming, learning by doing, but I need your advice for my project.

This is how it should look like:

[image]

Comment: could you share a drawing of how you imagine it to look like?

Comment: @MarkHim I included the drawing ;)

Comment: thanks, see my answer. I think the tableHeaderView is your way to go here

Comment: @leyke077 best way to do is as said by MarkHim i.e tableviewheader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In case you only want only one `UICollectionViewCell`, you could embed a `UICollectionView` to your first `UITableViewCell` and set the `delegate` and `dataSource` to your `UITableViewController`.
2. In case you want to design it a bit more reusable, you could create a `UICollectionViewController` and embed it to your cell. <- I suggest you do that

**Update:**

According to the drawing, you might be interested in using the tableHeaderView for the gallery instead of a static cell. Both solutions from above (1 and 2) are applicable there, but using the TableHeaderView is much more convenient. You can set it via

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = yourGalleryCollectionView
```

Comment: I'll try it with tableHeaderView, then I need to set the collectionview delegate and datasource to self ?

Comment: Yes make your tableViewController the delegate and, and make sure it implements the collectionview delegate and dataSource protocol

Comment: I don't use a tableviewController, instead a uiviewcontroller with a tableview

Comment: I am having trouble setting the height of the tableheaderview and setting detailTableView.tableHeaderView?.backgroundcolor = UIColor.greenColor() doesn't do anything, plus my image won't be displayed, maybe the whole collectionview isn't displayed..

Comment: Can't really help you without more info. Try starting simple to debug: create an empty uiview, set the frame (the height is relevant), and set its backgroundColor. Then do self.tableView.tableHeaderView = yourSimpleView

Comment: I now have the collectionView in the tableHeaderView with the right height and a backgroundcolor. I wrote print("cell for row at index path") into my collectionview method, but it doesn't get called. I have set the galleyCollectionView.delegate and .dataSource to self..

Comment: Since it is definately possible to solve your problem with tableHeaderView, you should close this question and consider starting a new question with your new problem and showing some of your code. I will gladly look there as well. Comments are not really good for problem solving here

Comment: I forgot to change vc.detailsTableView.reloadData() to vc.galleryCollectionView.reloadData() ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use collection view as a subview of tableview cell to show photo gallery. You can implement its delegate datasource in same class.